# Heroku deploy "Precompiling assets failed" on git push

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, deployment

We used the Heroku fork command to clone our production Rails 3 application for some testing. This was successful.

We are now attempting to push changes to the new forked app via a standard heroku git push deploy.

We are getting "Precompiling assets failed." and "Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app" errors on each attempt.

This exact repo is used for updates to our production application with no problems.

Can you direct me to how we might troubleshoot this?

Comment: Can you provide the Rails version and Ruby version you are using?

Comment: You'll likely have a problem with one of your CSS / JS files - is there any way you could show us the logs? There'll be an error reference somewhere

Answer (score 0):

try this in your config/application.rb

config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false

Answer (score 0):

Also, check if you included gem 'turbolinks' in your Gemfile. In my case I had failed to deploy the app multiple times (even after modifying my application.rb file via adding 'initialize_on_precompile') until I changed my Gemfile and installed missing gem.

Also, if you did not see before, there is some useful info concerning forking and deploying on Heroku (section "Deploy"): https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/fork-app