# More verbose heroku deployment fail reason

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, heroku

I have similar error like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20713705/heroku-deploy-precompiling-assets-failed-on-git-push)

`remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed`

My question is not why it fails, but rather **how could I get more verbose information from heroku**?

`heroku logs -t` doesn't work because it's a fresh app.

Answer (score 0):

In `heroku logs` command `-t` means `tail` and will show only new logs since you start this command. You can look at previous logs by using `heroku logs` without passing extra options.

Also it may be helpful to install add-on for log management like [Papertrail](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/papertrail) or [Logentries](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/logentries)